# APPEND SELECTED RECORDS TO TABLE

Tags: sql, vb.net-2010

SQLserver database contain two Tables EmpList and SalarySheet now I want to transfer selected records into SalarySheet Table from EmpList Table Filter by "Onduty".

I'm using VB2010 Windows Form.

Answer (score 0):

Some information about the layout of the tables involved would be a big help, but I'll take a very general stab at it.

Assuming that EmpList and SalarySheet have identical table structures the following might work:

```
INSERT INTO SalarySheet
  SELECT * FROM EmpList
    WHERE Status = "Onduty"
```

I'm just guessing that the filtering field is "Status" - you'll probably need to change this to use the correct field.  And this may not work at all if the fields in SalarySheet and EmpList don't match exactly.

Good luck.